# JSON not getting saved correctly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

So I'm pulling data from an API and want to save only specific dicts and list from the JSON response. The problem is that when I dump the data inside the loop it creates very weird looking data in the file which isn't actually JSON.

```
r=requests.get(url,headers=header)
result=r.json()
with open ('myfile.json','a+') as file:
    for log in result['logs']:
        hello=json.dump(log['log']['driver']['username'], file)
        hello=json.dump(log['log']['driver']['first_name'],file)
        hello=json.dump(log['log']['driver']['last_name'],file)
        for event in log['log']['events']:
            hello=json.dump(event['event']['id'],file)
            hello=json.dump(event['event']['start_time'],file)
            hello=json.dump(event['event']['type'],file)
            hello=json.dump(event['event']['location'],file)
```

The end goal here is to convert this data into a CSV. The only reason I'm saving it to a JSON file is so that I can load it and save it into a CSV then. The API endpoint I'm targeting is Logs:

https://developer.keeptruckin.com/reference#get-logs

Comment: In the loop(s), build your object (dict) how you want it, then *once* at the very end, `json.dump()` it into a file.

Comment: What would you like the JSON to look like for each row of the CSV? Provide a small sample if possible.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add a description of what the rows of the CSV file should have in them because I don't think there's much advantage to having this intermediate JSON-to-JSON conversion step if that's your ultimate goal.

Comment: @martineau Here's an example of what I'm getting on my terminal when I run the python script with print:

    Driver ID:  benpa
    First Name:  Demo
    Last Name:  One
    ID:  1234566
    Start Time:  2019-03-07T00:00:00-05:00
    Type:  driving
    Location:  Knoxville, TN
    ID:  1234565
    Start Time:  2019-03-07T01:20:47-05:00
    Type:  on_duty
    Location:  9.2 mi NE of Cleveland, TN

    Driver ID:  laet
    First Name:  Demo
    Last Name:  Two
    ID:  1234567
    Start Time:  2019-03-07T00:00:00-05:00
    Type:  driving
    Location:  Chattanooga, TN

Comment: @martineau the ID is basically the driving event ID. I only want to pull these specific things from the whole JSON response. I'm pulling them fine, it's just that I want to now save these into a CSV with their respective columns such as Driver ID and then displaying multiple events for that driver. Then moving onto the next driver and then multiple events for him in thei respective columns such as "Event Type" "Location" etc

Comment: OK, I think I understand. All rows of a CSV file generally need the same number of fields in them, so it looks like the driver's names will have to be repeated on every associated event row. You might be able to get around that by making them empty strings on all but the first row of a group of them for the same driver.

Comment: @martineau I'm okay with the driver names getting repeated for every event. How do I add all this data in the CSV without first converting the separated data into a JSON file, and then importing it again and putting it into a CSV, that's the problem.

Comment: @martineau Thank you so much. Looks like it worked. Quick question, is it possible to split the date and time such that the date gets entered in a separate column and the time in a separate one? Also, Is it possible to name the column headers at the top, from inside the script?

Comment: @martineau It worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @GBrandt has the right idea as far as creating valid JSON output goes, but as I said in a comment, I don't think that JSON-to-JSON conversion step is really necessary — since you could just create the CSV file from the JSON you already have:

(Modified to also split `start_time` into two separate fields as per you follow-on question.)

```
result = r.json()

with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for log in result['logs']:
        username = log['log']['driver']['username']
        first_name = log['log']['driver']['first_name']
        last_name = log['log']['driver']['last_name']

        for event in log['log']['events']:
            id = event['event']['id']
            start_time = event['event']['start_time']
            date, time = start_time.split('T')  # Split time into two fields.
            _type = event['event']['type']  # Avoid using name of built-in.
            location = event['event']['location']
            if not location:
                location = "N/A"
            writer.writerow(
                (username, first_name, last_name, id, date, time, _type, location))
```

Comment: stardamore: Note that the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` may not be necessary — and leaving it out would make the csv file created slightly smaller. Also note I don't think you should have accepted my answer since it's doesn't really address the question you asked about saving JSON (although I genuinely appreciate the gesture).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're just dumping individual JSON strings into the file in an unstructured way.

`json.dump` will not magically create a JSON dict-like object and save it into the file. See:

```
json.dump(log['log']['driver']['username'], file)
```

What it actually does there is just stringifying the driver's username and dumping it right into the file, so the file will have only a string, not a JSON object (which I'm guessing is what you want). It **is** JSON, just not really useful.

What you're looking for is this:

```py
r=requests.get(url,headers=header)
result=r.json()
with open ('myfile.json','w+') as file:
    logs = []
    for log in result['logs']:
        logs.append({
            'username': log['log']['driver']['username'],
            'first_name': log['log']['driver']['first_name'],
            'last_name': log['log']['driver']['last_name'],
            # ...
            'events': [
                ({
                    'id': event['event']['id'],
                    'start_time': event['event']['start_time'],
                    # ...
                }) for event in log['log']['events']
            ]
        })
    json.dump(logs, file)
```

Also, I would recommend not using append mode on JSON files, a `.json` is expected to hold a single JSON object (as far as I'm concerned).

Comment: That makes sense, but I seem to be getting errors when I check the JSON data on JSON Lint:

Error: Parse error on line 21:
...:25:45-05:00" }]} { "username": "laet
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Comment: @stardamore: That's strange because this [online JSON validator](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator) I just tried indicates that the contents of the file created _are_ valid (although I used my own input data). Note it's creating what is called an "array" in JSON (which like a `list` in Python). There's also a nested `event` array in each object in the outer array.

Comment: GBrandt: Actually, your code is generating a JSON "**array**" (see [format specification](http://json.org)) of JSON "**objects**", which is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

How about the code below (A sample json is loaded from a file instead of via HTTP call in order to get data to work with).

Sample JSON taken from https://developer.keeptruckin.com/reference#get-logs

```
import json

with open('input.json', 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

data_to_collect = []
logs = data['logs']
with open('output.json', 'w') as f_out:
    for log in logs:
        _log = log['log']
        data_to_collect.append({key: _log['driver'].get(key) for key in ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']})
        data_to_collect[-1]['events'] = []
        for event in _log['events']:
            data_to_collect[-1]['events'].append(
                {key: event['event'].get(key) for key in ['id', 'start_time', 'type', 'location']})
    json.dump(data_to_collect, f_out)
```

Output file

```
[
  {
    "username": "demo_driver",
    "first_name": "Demo",
    "last_name": "Driver",
    "events": [
      {
        "start_time": "2016-10-16T07:00:00Z",
        "type": "driving",
        "id": 221,
        "location": "Mobile, AL"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2016-10-16T09:00:00Z",
        "type": "sleeper",
        "id": 474,
        "location": null
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2016-10-16T11:00:00Z",
        "type": "driving",
        "id": 475,
        "location": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```